# CreateWindow с тонкой рамкой и без Title Bar

Tags: delphi, winapi

Используя `CreateWindow` я уже перепробовал почти все возможные параметры `dwStyle`, но сделать окно с тонкой рамкой без `Title Bar`у меня не получилось. Может это надо делать совсем в другом месте?

Comment: @Alekcvp Всё пробовал, а это как-то пропустил. Спасибо, работает!

Comment: Перенёс в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте `WS_POPUP or WS_DLGFRAME` или `WS_POPUP or WS_BORDER`.
При этом `dwExStyle := 0`.